# Can't compare NSData header to string in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, byte, ascii, nsdata

I am trying to compare the header (first bytes of NSData) against a string, I can successfully print the string, but comparing doesn't work.

This is what I've tried:

```
var dataHeader:NSString = NSString(bytes: data.bytes, length: min(data.length, 8), encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)!

println(dataHeader)
result: PK
```

The ASCII of "PK" is 0x50 0x4B.

When I try the following, nothing happens:

```
if dataHeader == "PK" {

}
```

Maybe I'm a noob but I don't have any ideas left, so does anyone have an idea on how to solve this? 
I am guessing it has something to do with the string encoding, but after doing a lot of research, I still can't figure it out.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `println(data)` to see the data and it's length, add that to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible there are other non-printing characters after the "PK" if this is binary data? What's the length of the string `dataHeader`?

If there are other funny characters after, you can truncate the string or use NSString's `hasPrefix:` method:

```
if dataHeader.hasPrefix("PK") {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: This was it! I have tried something similar, but I wasn't aware of the .hasPrefix function. Thanks!